# How to Prevent Composer from Updating Plugin?

Tags: plugins, composer, auto-updates

I have a plugin installed from a well known Craft developer. I have made significant tweaks and changes to the plugin and need to prevent it from updating. Is there an easy line of code to add to the composer.json file to prevent it from updating? I may have to go the route of breaking it out into our my plugin but for time reasons I am looking for simple ways to prevent updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have version 1.2.3 of the plugin installed and you don't want to Composer to update past that version, you'd just modify your `composer.json` file so it's locked to that exact version.

```
"require": {
    "plugindeveloper/pluginhandle": "1.2.3"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed on some of our Craft installs, when running composer update in ssh, it would automatically update all plugins that had updates available. Some of the installs didn't do this. I'm guessing it's some server feature or composer setting that may be causing this.